# git log usage: finding the most frequent committers for a given time period

Tags: git, git-log

For a given sub-directory in a git repository, how can I find who are the most frequent committers for a given period of time?

As of now I used git shortlog as follows:

```
git shortlog -sn -- path/to/subdir
```

But problem is this is giving data since beginning. I am trying to find this data for a window of time, e.g., last 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine with `since` for a time limit:

```
git --no-pager shortlog -sn --since="2017-01-12T16:36:00-07:00" -- path/to/dir
```

Is what you need. `since` can be a year back. If there are a ton of authors (more than display height) then pipe this into `head` or `less`.